# multiple data ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two forms ( request and feedback ) for which I want to send the data through jQuery Ajax call.

so if user send request, subject request will be appear.
if user send feedback, subject feedback will be appear.

this my code

```
$("#feedback,#request").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "You Got Feedback from " + name + "&message=" + message,
        success: function(data) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

i just wanna change subject, You Got Feedback or You Got Request.

but i don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operation for it:

```
var subject = "You Got " + 
              (this.id === "feedback") ? "Feedback" : "Request" +" from " + name;  

data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + subject +  "&message=" + message,
//---add the subject here--------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

or with sending data object:

```
var subject = "You Got " + 
              (this.id === "feedback") ? "Feedback" : "Request" +" from " + name;

data: {name : name,
      email : email,
      subject : subject, 
      message : message},
```

Comment: can't get you. When does it happen?